# Change color in a text row or a word in a draft file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a way in Android studio to change the color for a line of text or for a single word? I keep track of my previous code in a draft simple file in Android Studio and i want to change the default white color in some lines to iterate easier.

[image: Simple file in package]

[image: Example of line that could help if it changed color]